Keras branch model issue
I have constructed the following CNN model:
def create_model(input_shape=(128, 128, 3)):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape, name='inputs')

    # main block
    main_block = keras.Sequential([
     bunch of layers
    ], name='main_block')
    main_block_outputs = main_block(inputs)


    # branch 1: black
    branch_black = keras.Sequential([
       bunch of layers
    ], name='black')
    branch_black_outputs = branch_black(main_block_outputs)


    # branch 2: square
    branch_square = keras.Sequential([
       bunch of layers
    ], name='square')
    branch_square_outputs = branch_square(main_block_outputs)

    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[branch_black_outputs, branch_square_outputs], name='model')
model = create_model()
# expand model architecture to show all layers
model.summary(expand_nested=True)
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=True, show_layer_activations=True)

when I plot this model though, I can see the two branches but they are both called "Sequential". Worse still when I compile it and run it using the following. I get summerised values, not values broken down by branch. I know I am doing something basic wrong but I cant see to work it out...


model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=4e-3),
    loss={
        'black': losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
        'square': losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
    },
    metrics={
        'black': metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(),
        'square': metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
    }
)

Appreciate your patience, I new to this.
I was expecting a plot with named branches "black" and "square" and metric for each branch once run.
